# React - Dealing with lower components needing to render upper ones

Tags: reactjs

I have the following situation, I have a search bar and it'll be used for the user to input the username that he wants to retrieve repositories from github. Once he clicks the search button the RepositoriesList should be rendered and receive the response from the API call.

**App.js**

```
  const App = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <div id="searchBar">
        <SearchBar username={username} setUsername={setUsername} />
      </div>
      <div id="repositoriesList">
        <RepositoriesList username={username} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**SearchBar.js**

```
      <form onSubmit={handleSearch}>
        <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Input your username' className='border-2 text-sm'
          value={props.username} onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type='submit' value='Search' className='border-2 rounded-lg'>Search</button>
      </form>
```

My first thought as learning react was to extract the search bar and the repositories list into two components, but my problem arrives as to **how should I communicate to repositories list that the search bar received a "submit" event and pass the final user to repositories.**

**Also who should treat the data and/or make the API call to github? The searchbar or repositories list?**

I tried to solve it like this

```
const App = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [searched, setSearched] = useState(true)

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <div id="searchBar">
        <SearchBar username={username} setUsername={setUsername} setSearched={setSearched}/>
      </div>
      {searched &&
      <div id="repositoriesList">
        <RepositoriesList username={username} />
      </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

but that doesn't work, as after the searchbar has setted the searched to true once, the repositories list will keep updating with the user as you are typing, not once you are finished and click the button. Maybe I shouldn't use **onChange?** inside SearchBar.js?

Answer (score 0):

React.js uses unidirectional data flow, which means the parents usually have more states and control the flow of data to the children which are stateless components usually take props from their parents. what you are having a problem with is a common scenario in react and here is how you go about doing it the reacty way:

in this particular case you have a parent and two children and the parent should be responsible for feeding data to the children since they cannot communicate with each other.

```
App.js
    |- SearchBar.js
    |- RepositoriesList.js
```

in the parent component:

```
const App = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [searched, setSearched] = useState(true)
  const [result, setResult] = useState("")

  const usernameInputHandler = (event) => { 
   //update the state of username to what user has typed
 }

  // this should be performed onSubmit when the user submits the form.
  const performSearch = (event) => { 
   //perform the api request
   //update state result to the new result returned from api
 }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <div id="searchBar">
        <SearchBar username={username} usernameInputHandler={usernameInputHandler} />
      </div>
      <div id="repositoriesList">
        <RepositoriesList username={username} result={result} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

then inside each component all you do is just get the props sent by parent components and show them, and you will also get the handler functions and use them the way you want.

for example inside SearchBar.js:

```
 <form onSubmit={props.performSearch}>
        <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Input your username' className='border-2 text-sm'
          value={props.username} onChange={props.usernameInputHandler} />
        <button type='submit' value='Search' className='border-2 rounded-lg'>Search</button>
 </form>
```

also inside RepositoriesList.js you could create a list of items and show the results since the parent sends them as props to children and it can be accessed using props.result.

at the end to answer your question:

> how should I communicate to repositories list that the search bar
>   received a "submit" event and pass the final user to repositories?

you can communicate data and logic between them through their parents.